# Modified query with ManyToMany

Tags: mysql, spring-data-jpa

I've problem with update query in Spring. I can't add new authorities for user. This is my solution:

UserRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);
Optional<User> findByIdAndAuthorities(Long id, Authorities auth);

@Modifying
@Transactional
@Query("UPDATE User u SET u.authorities = :authorities WHERE u.id=:id")
void setUserAuthorities(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("authorities") List<Authorities> authorities);}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {

private UserRepository userRepository;
private AuthoritiesRepository authoritiesRepository;

@Autowired
public AdminController(UserRepository userRepository, AuthoritiesRepository authoritiesRepository){
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
    this.authoritiesRepository = authoritiesRepository;
}


@PostMapping("/addAdmin")
public String addAdmin(User user, Model model){
    Optional<User> userDB = userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

    if(!userDB.isPresent()){
        model.addAttribute("userError","User doesn't exist");
    }
    else{
        List<Authorities> adminAdd  = new ArrayList<>();
        adminAdd.addAll(adminAdd);
        userRepository.setUserAuthorities(userDB.get().getId(), adminAdd);
    }

    return "createAdmin";
}}
```

When I send form I get error:

```
2020-05-21 18:46:20.291 ERROR 8564 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'set .=null where id=1' at line 1
2020-05-21 18:46:20.308 ERROR 8564 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement] with root cause
```

User connect with Auth by@ManyToMany. Someone has idea ?

Answer (score -1):

JPQL updates only allow to update

See section 4.10 of the JPA specification:

```
update_statement ::= update_clause [where_clause]
update_clause ::= UPDATE entity_name [[AS] identification_variable]
                     SET update_item {, update_item}*
update_item ::= [identification_variable.]{single_valued_embeddable_object_field.}*
                     {state_field | single_valued_object_field} = new_value
```

I see two major options:

1. Simply load the `User` entities, set the `Authorities` and let JPA flush the changes to the database.
2. If you don't want to or can't load the entities you may use SQL to manipulate the data in the database directly.