# Updating many to many tables with spring data jpa, incompatible types

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I cant get this table to update bc of an incompatible types error. The user table attempts to save a set of attributes, but my sql syntax seems to be throwing an error that causes the set of attributes to be broken into individual attributes. I have these two classes, User and Attributes, with a many to many table in between.

```
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class Attributes implements Serializable {



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;



    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "attributes",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
}
```

User Class

```
@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class User implements UserDetails, Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_attributesXXX",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "attributes_id",referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Attributes> attributes;
}
```

I attempt to save to my repository, getting the set of attributes from the front end with this method below.

```
    @RequestMapping("/bulk_update")
    public String bulkUpdate(@RequestParam(value = "checkboxName", required = false) String[] checkboxValue, @RequestParam(value = "attributeName", required = false) Set<Attributes> attributeValue, HttpServletRequest request
    ) {

        for (String fun : checkboxValue){
            for ( Attributes fun2 : attributeValue){

                User user_to_update2 = userRepository.findUserById(Integer.parseInt(fun));

                userRepository.updateUserQRAttributes(user_to_update2.getId(), attributeValue);


        }
        }


        return "redirect:/manageusers";
    }
```

When I do the final sql transaction, I get in compatible types. How could this be? I am passing in a Set it seems.

```
 @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("update User set attributes= :attributes where id = :id") // escape role,
        //mark the role param,
        //mark the role as a val which should be changed by the dependency which executes the query
    int updateUserQRAttributes(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("attributes") Set<Attributes> attributes);
```

And this throws the error of

```
Parameter value [gov.mycolorado.oauth2.models.Attributes@392defb9] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [gov.mycolorado.oauth2.models.Attributes@392defb9] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]
```

```
21:35:54.290 [http-nio-5000-exec-6] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [gov.mycolorado.oauth2.models.Attributes@1630134d] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [gov.mycolorado.oauth2.models.Attributes@1630134d] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [gov.mycolorado.oauth2.models.Attributes@1630134d] did not match expected type [java.util.Set (n/a)]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryParameterBindingValidator.validate(QueryParameterBindingValidator.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.validate(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingImpl.setBindValue(QueryParameterBindingImpl.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryParameterBindingsImpl.expandListValuedParameters(QueryParameterBindingsImpl.java:636)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doExecuteUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1616)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1594)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:256)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:125)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you posted only the exception message and not the stack trace I'm not sure what exactly the exception is about. 
But this won't work at all.

You are trying to perform a JPQL `UPDATE` statement to set a collection. 
This is not supported. 
JPQL `UPDATE` only supports single valued attributes in the updated clause:

See section 4.10 of the JPA specification:

```
update_statement ::= update_clause [where_clause]
update_clause ::= UPDATE entity_name [[AS] identification_variable]
                     SET update_item {, update_item}*
update_item ::= [identification_variable.]{single_valued_embeddable_object_field.}*
                     {state_field | single_valued_object_field} = new_value
```

You can either load the entities set the relationships as desired and flush the changes for example by closing the transaction, basically the normal JPA workflow.

Alternatively you can execute SQL statements effectively performing the update. 
This of course will be a little more complex since you'll have to determine what rows to insert, which to delete and which to update.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61956946/66686

Comment: I included the entire stack trace. Any chance you could help me out w this query?

Comment: I already did. It won't work you need to implement one of the two alternatives layed out in my answer (and the linked one).